Guidance on EventHub data ingestion process
I am sending the events from the application to eventHub.I am able to monitoring the health graph of eventHub due to limited access. there I have noticed that Metric Events received and Events processes count but on examining the configured primary table for the particular eventHub no recent data was ingested.
Currently I have been suggested to enable the capture feature for the eventHub and configure storage account which has few of logs categories enabled. Once that capture feature is got enabled 1. What do I need to check reagrding the data ingestion failure?
2. If data ingestion is ongoing, what steps can I take to ensure successful ingestion into the configured primary table?

cluster01> diagnostic settings > Avro> capture ON >select logs categories > archived to storage account > specify the storage account Name > SAVE. these are steps we are following as of now so, I have a question that, does it affect only that eventHub or all eventHubs available in that cluster?

Looking forward to the suggestions.

The .show ingestion failures command return all recorded ingestion failures, providing details such as operation ID, database, table, failed timestamp, ingestion source path, failure details, failure kind, root activity ID, operation kind, error code, principal, user, ingestion properties, and number of sources.
.show ingestion failures

You can also use filters to narrow down the results. For instance, to retrieve ingestion failures for a specific operation ID, you can use:
.show ingestion failures with (OperationId = '3827def6-0773-4f2a-859e-c02cf395deaf')

This the reference link for .show ingestion failures command   in  Azure Data Explorer.

When sending messages in event Hub , you include custom properties in the message properties section.

these custom properties to be ingested into Azure Data Explorer, you need to embed them into the body section of the event data object.
The following example compares the events data object containing custom property  customProperty  as  defined  by Event Hubs (Top) with the  embedded  property required for ingestion (down).
{
"body":{
"value": 42
},
"properties":{
"customProperty": "123456789"
}
}


{
"body":{
"value": 42,
"customProperty": "123456789"
}
}


For more details refer  to this link for Ingest from event hub - Azure Data Explorer 


Follow this for this steps in so to create  table

Refer to this link for Continuous data export  Azure Data Explorer 

Refer to  this so to get data from storage to Azure Data Explorer tables .

You followed this process below
cluster01> diagnostic settings > Avro> capture ON >select logs categories > archived to storage account > specify the storage account Name > SAVE.
It only track the all event in the Azure Data Explorer cluster only and send to  storage. It don't effect the event Hub which are connected to  data source/ added to the database.

